# Why can't create keycloak 21.1.2 first admin?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

Why can't create keycloak 21.1.2 first admin?
Showing error with status 403 when creating first admin.

ERROR:
An internal server error has occurred

[create first admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3m1.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcUej.png)

[this is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtSFh.png)

How to create keycloak 21.1.2 first admin?
or How to insert the first admin into a postgres database?